# This isn't a (blank) as much as it is a (blank)

Tags: phrases

Can anyone tell me what this means and can you please give an example of how to use it? My teacher used it earlier today, and I still don't get it.

Comment: What was the version that your teacher used?

Comment: "This isn't a love letter as much as it was a confession" i think

Comment: Personally I prefer ***so** much...* As in *This isn't a question so much as it's a rant.* (That's just an example - I'm not saying it about *this* question! :)

Comment: It's just an idiomatically established way of saying *the **second** expression fits the context better than the **first***. Or *It's more of a (blank2) than a (blank1)*

Comment: thank you so much! i get it now!

Answer (score 1):

> - This isn't an A as much as a B.
> - This isn't an A so much as a B.
> - This isn't an A; It's more of a B
> - This isn't an A as much as it is a B.
> - It's not so much of an A, more of a B.

All of these, and other variations, are commonly used ways to say that B fits the context better then A. These forms can be used ironically or sarcastically, as in:

> It's not so much of a deal, it's more of a scam.

This construction can be used for humor, as in:

> This isn't therapy as much as a mental strip-tease.

Or it can be used in a straightforward manner, such as:

> It isn't a lake so much as a pond.

Context and tone govern how a particular use is to be understood. I suspect the "so much" versions have been favored by the comparatively recent popularity of versions of:

> X ,Yes. Y, not so much.

To mean  that Y is not at all acceptable, or does not occur.

In any case, these forms are fairly common, but have no special meaning really beyond their literal meaning. This is not an idiom that has a meaning different from the sum of its words.